# Continuity of this function

Tags: limits, continuity, limits-without-lhopital

I have this function:

> $f(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> \tan(\frac{\pi x}{4}),  & \lvert x \rvert \lt 1 \\
> x, & \lvert x \rvert \ge 1
> \end{cases}$

I presumed it as continuous just because I analysed the limit as the function approaches 1.

> ### $\lim \limits_{x \to 1^+}f(x)=(1)=1$
>
> ### $\lim \limits_{x \to 1^-}f(x)=\tan(\frac{\pi (1)}{4})=\tan(\frac{\pi}{4})=1$
>
> ### $\lim \limits_{x \to -1^+}f(x)=(-1)=-1$
>
> ### $\lim \limits_{x \to -1^-}f(x)=\tan(\frac{\pi (-1)}{4})=-\tan(\frac{\pi}{4})=-(1)=-1$

Are there any cases in which the function is discontinuous?  I must not use taking derivatives or anything higher, just using basic limit definitions should be used: the problem assumes that I don't know anything from higher level calculus.

Comment: You may also want to consider $-1$? (or use the fact that $f$ is odd to only have to deal with non-negative numbers).

Comment: @ClementC. Good point. I just assumed it either way would be right.

Comment: Correct, $x=\pm 1$ is the part that takes work.  $\tan(x)$ is continuous on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, where you are using that it is continuous on $[-\pi/4,\pi/4]$, and $f(x)=x$ is continuous everywhere.

Comment: @mathematician You might want to write that as an answer, because it might be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, $x=\pm1$ is the part that takes work. $\tan(x)$ is continuous on (−π/2,π/2), where you are using that it is continuous on [−π/4,π/4], and $f(x)=x$ is continuous everywhere.